# How to copy a specific commit to another Branch?

Tags: git

In my `git` master I have 2 branches as `production` and `testing`. I do all work with testing. at present example my production version is 5. my testing version is 20. now I would like to update the production version from testing version of 15.

for that, how can i select the testing version of 15 and copy or merge to production version of 5? ( if the new testing version commit as id of 6 in the production version that' fine )

if anything wrong here please excuse me.

I don't have any idea. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you checkout (`git checkout`) the testing branch at the specific commit for version 15. then create a temporary branch `git checkout -b version15merge` and merge `git checkout production && git merge version15merge` this stuff into your `production` branch.

Answer (score 1):

Use `git cherry-pick` and the SHA1 of the commit you want to copy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy single commits, use `git cherry-pick`.
If you want to merge all changes in `testing` up to `15`, just use `git merge 15` to merge over the changes to `production`.

Comment: I am trying like this: but getting error :
`
C:\Tutorials\try>git cherry-pick 3bdb71b https://github.com/3gwebtrain/color-palette.git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` - any idea the wrong what i do here?

Comment: You cannot cherry pick from a remote URL. You have to add this repository as remote if you did not have already and fetch its changes, then you cherry-pick. Except you have some addon like `git-spindle` or `hub` where you can do things like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git cherry-pick <commit-hash from the source branch >` when your destination branch is checked out. In your case find the commit-hash of version 15 in *testing* branch and then checkout the master branch and run the below:

```
git cherry-pick <commit-hash of version 15 from testing branch>
```

Comment: Getting error like this : 
`
C:\Tutorials\try\color-palette>git cherry-pick f487636
error: could not apply f487636... Update start.txt
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'`

Comment: This means you have conflict in some file when trying to cherry-pick the changes. Resolve the conflicts and then `git add ` the files and commit it

Comment: so, both of the version need to check-out in local system?

Comment: No just open the files mentioned in conflict message, here the `start.txt` and resolve the conflict from testing branch and master branch. You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/q/161813/3878940 to know more abou resolving conflicts